# If center of rhombus is $(\pi, e)$. FInd the equation of diagonal

Tags: analytic-geometry

Two sides of rhombus are parallel to $3x+4y+17=0$ and $4x+3y+16=0$. Center of rhombus is $(\pi, e)$, find the equation of its diagonal.

Is data in this question sufficient to find required diagonal?

Comment: Angle bisector of given lines will be parallel to the diagonal and diagonal will pass through centre.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon $ be  the angle bisector of the $2$ given lines $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ and $M(x_0,y_0)$ a point on it. Then, the distances of $M$ from the $2$ given lines will be equal. Thus, we have:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
d(M,\epsilon_1) = d(M,\epsilon_2)\\[2ex]
\dfrac{|3x_0 + 4y_0 + 17|}{\sqrt{3^2 + 4^2}} = \dfrac{|4x_0+3y_0+16|}{\sqrt{4^2+3^2}}\\[2ex]
|3x_0+4y_0+17| = |4x_0+3y_0+16|\\[2ex]
\end{array}$$
From the last equation, we get: 
$$ y_0 = -x_0 -\frac{33}{7} \text { or } y_0 = x_0 -1.$$

Thus, the slope of the diagonal is either $\lambda = -1$ or $\lambda = 1$. The equation of the diagonal is:
$$y-e = -1(x-\pi) \text { or  } y-e = 1(x-\pi)\\
\boxed{y =-x+\pi +e} \text { or } \boxed{y = x-\pi + e}.$$

Actually, these are the equations of the 2 diagonals.